# Let perl print multiple matches starting at the same position

Tags: perl

I want something like

```
print "$1\n" while("number123" =~ /(number.*?[0-9])/g);
```

to print out

```
number1
number2
number3
```

However, it only prints

```
number1
```

Can my goal be achieved with a regex, or is a loop unavoidable?

Comment: As "number2" is not even a substring of the original string, single regex match doesn't sound possible.

Comment: What do you have against loops? Also, "while" is a loop.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can print it with a regex and a post-fix loop.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $str = "number123";
say $1 while $str =~ s/(number\K\d)//g
```

Will print the desired output

```
number1
number2
number3
```

Note that the original string is destroyed, so use a copy if you wish to keep the original string intact.

Answer (score 1):

```perl
"number123" =~ /
   (number)
   [0-9]*?
   ([0-9])
   (?{ print("$1$2\n"); })
   (*FAIL)
/xg;
```